# How to push floated element to below another floated element?

Tags: css

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/195/

I'm trying to get the little blue dive to always sit tight in the corner, below the red but to the right of the big blue div.  How can this be achieved?

**CSS:**

```
.floated{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.big{
    height: 300px;
}
.with-padding{
    padding: 50px;
}
.yellow{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class='floated big'>FLOATED BIG</div>
<div class='floated with-padding yellow'>SHOULD BE NEXT TO FLOATED BIG</div>
<div class='floated'>push down</div>
```

Comment: An image might make it easier to see what you've got & why it's not what you want.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott check the jsfiddle, that's why I made it

Comment: The fiddle is helpful -- but a diagram or screenshot of what you expect can help, too.

Comment: External links should be discouraged if you can easily put everything required directly on SO.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/198/

Comment: @A.O. Nice and clean. Not sure if it matters to the OP, but the small blue div goes beneath the big blue div if the red div's height is larger than that of the big blue div. http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/199/

Comment: @showdev that's a good point. In that case you would most likely need to implement some wrappers/container divs to keep everything maintainable (probably the best solution for this anyway lol).

Comment: @Okuma.Scott - jsfiddle is *way* easier than making an image.  And good luck preaching that to half of all posts on SO... it's a tool that serves its purpose better than any screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you nest the `red div` and the `small blue div` in their own container div.

Then, float that `container div` next to the `big blue div`.

```
<div class='floated big blue'>FLOATED BIG</div>
<div class="floated">
  <div class='with-padding yellow'>SHOULD BE NEXT TO FLOATED BIG</div>
  <div class='blue'>push down</div>
</div>
```

If you need the small blue div to be "shrink wrapped", you can float it:

```
<div class='floated big blue'>FLOATED BIG</div>
<div class="floated">
  <div class='with-padding yellow'>SHOULD BE NEXT TO FLOATED BIG</div>
  <div class='floated blue'>push down</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PTSkR/197/

Answer (score 0):

While it's not exactly clear what you want, I think adding the clear:left attribute to the last floated div will give you the result you want. Something like:

```
.floated:last-of-type{
    clear:left;
}
```